# detail study of prototype in js

Tags: javascript, prototype

Consider those codes below:

```
//for extend classes
function extend(subClass,superClass){
  var F=function(){};
  F.prototype=superClass.prototype;
  subClass.prototype=new F();
  subClass.prototype.constructor=subClass;
}
//basic sender object
function Sender(){}
Sender.prototype = {
  ...
};
//interface
//extend method 1:
function BackendAdmin(){}
BackendAdmin.prototype.Sender = function(){};
extend(BackendAdmin.Sender,Sender); //will generate prototype of undefined error
//extend method 2:
function BackendAdmin(){
  this.Sender = function(){};
  extend(this.Sender,Sender);// Seems can not be extended
}
// instance
var myadmin=new BackendAdmin();
myadmin.Sender.StartLoading(); // do not have method for method 2.
```

In this case, I would like to create a sender instance, which inhire the methods of basic sender class, in BackendAdmin, also, I need to override the method of sender in BackendAdmin if necessary. But, it seems it doesn't work in both cases unless I use something like this:

```
this.sender = new Sender();
```

How can I use the extend function?

Comment: Nothing against Propotype but it's getting quite old...

Comment: Oh, my bad I just saw the `prototypejs` tag. [PrototypeJS](http://www.prototypejs.org/) is an old JS library, but it seems that what you mean is `prototype`, I edited your tags.

Comment: @elclanrs I see. yes I am meaning prototype, not prototype.js. thank you elclanrs. Do you have some idea of this question?

Comment: At present you have a mixture of techniques; part of your code indicates you want inheritance , part of it indicates you want a Sender object in your BackendAdmin instance. Which is it?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan I want a sender object in backendadmin to inherit the basic sender object which is function sender(){...}